# How to reconfigure/restored Xdb Index?

Tags: solr, indexing

My Local `Xdb` consists of only 4 Docs, By Using `Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr` command, I already rebuild my `xdb` index. But I am unable to get all data in Solr.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As per your information, your xDB only have 4 docs and in Solr it is showing 4 records. So what is the issue you are actually facing?

Comment: Do you have any identified contacts in xDB or they are all anonymous? Please note that indexing of anonymous contacts is disabled by default for performance reasons. https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-platform/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts-in-the-xdb-index.html

Comment: xDB has more records, but in solr it’s only showing 4 Docs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have zero contacts in your xDB index.

The docs that you are seeing in those screen shots are default ones that are used to manage the index (for example - when a rebuild is triggered).

An actual xDB contact record would begin more like this:

```
{
        "id":"a2db255477a60200000006a1b996f809",
        "contactid_s":"be3fb5f989fb000000000683c1c2fe36",
        "facets.profilescores.lastmodified_dt":"2023-02-08T10:28:38.016Z",
        "facets.ipinfo.lastmodified_dt":"2023-02-08T10:28:38.016Z",
        "facets.webvisit.screen.screenheight_i":480,
        "engagementvalue_i":0,
        "lastmodified_dt":"2023-02-08T10:28:38.016Z",
        "duration.hours_i":0,
        .....
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, your problem is most likely due to having no **known contacts** in xDB.

When a contact is first created, they are assigned two annonymous identifiers **xDB.Tracker** and **Alias**, which have `ContactIdentifierType.Anonymous` (stored in DB as '0').

When a contact is identified (you must do this in code using IdentifyAs() method), you assign a new identifier which has `ContactIdentifierType.Known` (stored in DB as '1').

To confirm this, try running this SQL command against your xDB tables:

```
SELECT A.ContactId
FROM [Your_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[ContactIdentifiers] A
INNER JOIN  [Your_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].Contacts B ON A.ContactId=B.ContactId
where IdentifierType=1

UNION

SELECT A.ContactId
FROM [Your_Xdb.Collection.Shard1].[xdb_collection].[ContactIdentifiers] A
INNER JOIN  [Your_Xdb.Collection.Shard1].[xdb_collection].Contacts B ON A.ContactId=B.ContactId
where IdentifierType=1
```

*Note: Dont ever run SQL queries directly against xDB tables in a production environment.*

I am guessing it will return 0 contacts.

You can switch over the config in your search indexer to index annonymous contacts by updating: `<your-xdb>\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_Data\Config\Sitecore\SearchIndexer\sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml`

Update this line to `true`:

```
<IndexAnonymousContactData>false</IndexAnonymousContactData>
```

Then click off a new rebuild using `Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr`